# Eigenvalues and inverse of matrix which has matrix entries

Tags: matrix

Suppose I have a $2\times2$ matrix which contains $2\times2$ matrices as entries, is there a clean way to find the inverse of such object and compute its eigenvalues/vectors?

My code is

```
entry1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};

entry2 = (N + L)/(2 LN)*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}} + (N - L)/(2 LN)*{{Cos[2 x], 
      Sin[2 x]}, {Sin[2 x], -Cos[2 x]}};

entry3  = rho*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}};

entry4 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};

M = MatrixForm[{{entry1, entry2}, {entry3, entry4}}];
```

Then

```
Det[M]
```

doesn't work as expected, it gives no result. Can this be done in mathematica? (Yes I know I shouln't be using these variable names)

Comment: First, you should not do `M = MatrixForm[...];` followed by `Det[M]` since `M` is wrapped in `MatrixForm`. Second, should not use `N` since that means something else in Mathematica. Third, what is `L` and `LN`? do these have numerical values? Fourth: `Det` takes a square matrix as input. Not a matrix of matrices. So you would need to convert that to a normal 2D matrix.

Comment: Use `ArrayFlatten[{{entry1, entry2}, {entry3, entry4}}]`, then `Det` will compute the result.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
entry1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};

entry2 = (n + L)/(2 LN)*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}} + (n - L)/(2 LN)*{{Cos[2 x], 
      Sin[2 x]}, {Sin[2 x], -Cos[2 x]}};

entry3 = rho*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}};

entry4 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
(M = ArrayFlatten[{{entry1, entry2}, {entry3, entry4}}]) // MatrixForm
Det[M]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]